# Annyang.js works when run in localhost but unable to access it from the application

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tableau-api, annyang

I have a very simple speech recognition code. When I run it in https://localhost:8080/demo.html the speech recognition works fine. But when Im trying to access the same in my Tableau extension api, the microphone prompt itself is not showing.

I enabled chrome flags Allow invalid certificates for resources loaded from localhost and Insecure origins treated as secure. Even then its not working from application. Any thing I'm missing ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="annyang.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    if (annyang) {
  var commands = {

'Hi': function() { alert('HI'); }
 };

  annyang.addCommands(commands);
  annyang.setLanguage('en');
  annyang.start();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Regards,
Arsha